# How to grant access to the RSA Key container while encrypting and decrypting a web.config file of an ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

I have been trying to encrypt and decrypt a we.config file of an ASP.Net application but in vain. Here are the steps I have executed successfully after logging into the command prompt using administrative privileges.

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

and then I created the custom exportable RSA Key Container

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pc “CustomKeys” -exp
```

but when I try to grant access to the RSA Container using

```
aspnet_regiis -pa “CustomKeys” “NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE”
```

it does apparently nothing. Here is the screenshot

[image]

[image]

Again when I try to update app’s web.config file to specify a customProvider
it throws exceptions saying keyContainerName , useMachineContainer attributes are not allowed.

How to grant access to the same ?

I tried several options which all failed saying the RSA Key Container is not found.

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pa "CustomKeys" "Network Service" -full

aspnet_regiis.exe -pa "CustomKeys" "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" -pku

aspnet_regiis -pa "CustomKeys" "DOMAIN\USER"

aspnet_regiis -pa "CustomKeys" "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool" -full
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure without granting access to the container whether users on other machines would be able to use it for decryption purposes . Please help me through.

Comment: Is there a reason you insist on using aspnet_regiis rather than launching an mmc snapin console and adding the key priviledge manually from there?

Comment: Not such only my org keeps insisting that way only

Comment: Does it even work if you try adding priviledges with the mmc snapin?

Comment: Really do not have much idea. Is that a third party tool or something ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms788967(v=VS.110).aspx From there you can assign user priviledges to private keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyContainerName and useMachineContainer attributes are not allowed problem fix..

After browsing the internet and going to many forums the answer lies in the version path of the code... there is a space in your code. version=2.0.0.0 not 2.0 0.0

```
<configProtectedData>
  <providers>
     <add name="MyProvider"
          type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0,
                Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,
                processorArchitecture=MSIL"
          keyContainerName="MyKeys" 
          useMachineContainer="true" />
  </providers>
```